# gnuplot: Create multiple boxplots from different data files on the same output

Tags: iteration, gnuplot, boxplot

I have a set of files that contain data that I want to produce a set of box plots for in order to compare them. I can get the data into gnuplot, but I don't know the correct format to separate each file into its own plot.

I have tried reading all the required files into a variable, which does work, however when the plot is produced, all the boxplots are on top of each other. I need to get gnuplot to index each plot along one space for each new data file.

For example, this produces the output with overlaying plots:

```
FILES = system("ls -1 /path/to/files/*")

plot    for [data in FILES] data using (1):($4)  with boxplot notitle
```

I know the X position is being stated explicitly there with the (1), but I'm not sure what to replace it with to get the position to move for each plot. This isn't a problem with other chart types, since they don't have the same field locating them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following.
You can access the file in your file list by index via `word(FILES,i)`. Check `help word` and `help words`. The code below assumes that you have some datafiles `Data0*.dat` in your directory. Maybe there is a smarter/shorter way to implement the xtic labels.

**Code:**

```
### boxplots from a list of files
reset session

# get a list of files (Windows)
FILES = system('dir /B "C:\Data\Data0*.dat"')

# set tics as filenames
set xtics ()    # remove xtics
set yrange [-2:27]
do for [i=1:words(FILES)] {
    set xtics add (word(FILES,i) i) rotate by 45 right
}

plot for [i=1:words(FILES)] word(FILES,i) u (i):2 w boxplot notitle
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly. I had managed to get something that worked by using a bash script to concatenate the data files into blocks and using the index function in gnuplot. This solution is neater however, as it doesn't require a wrapper script or the creation of a temporary file.